# Expired keys in Redis not cleaned up

Tags: redis, memory-leaks

I have a Redis database (5.0.6) that I use to cache some API call made by my application.

The application is used by around 400k users.

In every keys that we store in our Redis Database we also set an expiry time (usually around 2 hours).

Since a few days, it seems that my Redis database is not cleaning my expiry keys anymore...

I see that the memory used was around 200Mo a few weeks ago and is now above 1Go and it could continue to grow more if Kubernetes was not killing it when it reached the limit we set.

What could be the root cause about this issue ?

When I connect to Redis through its cli and when I run the command `info keyspace`, I have the following results:

> ## Keyspace
>
> db0:keys=216272,expires=216272,avg_ttl=54395557

As I understand the result, it is like if there were almost all the keys that have expired.

Any idea, why Redis is not cleaning them ?

Comment: Redis uses a lazy expiration mechanism. It expires keys when access and a second method to random expire a subset [https://redis.io/commands/expire/#:~:text=How%20Redis%20expires%20keys,will%20never%20be%20accessed%20again.]. Can you try accessing some of these keys and see if the keys are actually evicted to see it the eviction mechanism is working or not ?

Comment: avg_ttl=54395557 means that the average time till expiration is 15.1 hours - not 2 hours or less as you would expect

Comment: Thanks @LiorKogan !
You have spotted something wiered that helped me to spot a bug in our application ! So Redis is fine about this issue :-)